# How I can add progress bar with label with percentage of progress of upload in Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to upload video to server through Alamofire 4.0 and I want to add progress bar to show the percentage of upload process during uploading process , how I can do that through the same function of upload from Alamofire.

My code of upload function:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in



                        multipartFormData.append(url.absoluteURL!, withName: "videoFile", fileName: "alaa", mimeType: "mov")
                        multipartFormData.append("video".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "load")
                        multipartFormData.append("record".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "type")


                    }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
                        // code
                        print("uploaded")
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote directly from the AlamoFire docs:

> Upload Progress
>
> While your user is waiting for their upload to complete, sometimes it
>   can be handy to show the progress of the upload to the user. Any
>   UploadRequest can report both upload progress and download progress of
>   the response data using the uploadProgress and downloadProgress APIs.

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")

Alamofire.upload(fileURL, to: "https://httpbin.org/post")
    .uploadProgress { progress in // main queue by default
        print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
    .downloadProgress { progress in // main queue by default
        print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

Comment: where is the URL of video in this line ?
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")

Comment: It means to get the URL of a file named video.mov in your main bundle.

Comment: That is sample code, not code specific to your problem.That line creates a file url for a file called "video.mov" from the app bundle.

Comment: @DuncanC do you know what downloadProgress does in this example? I searched for a while and looked at the code of AlamoFire and can't figure it out. Is it the progress of download of the server's response?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.

```
            var imgData = Data()
            if image != nil {

                imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)!
            }

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image", fileName: "imagefilename", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

                for (key, value) in param {

                    //let data = (value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                    let data = (value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: key as! String)
                }
            },
                             usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                             to:fullLink,
                             method:.post,
                             headers:[:],
                             encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                                switch encodingResult {

                                case .success(let upload, _, _):

                                    upload.uploadProgress { progress in // main queue by default

                                        print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                                    }

                                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                                        debugPrint(response)

                                        if let TempresponseDict:NSDictionary = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {

                                            if (TempresponseDict.object(forKey: "response") as? String)?.caseInsensitiveCompare("success") == .orderedSame {

                                                CompletionHandler(true, TempresponseDict)
                                            }
                                            else {

                                                var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

                                                if let error = response.result.error as? AFError {

                                                    statusCode = error._code // statusCode private

                                                    switch error {

                                                    case .invalidURL(let url):
                                                        print("Invalid URL: \(url) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                    case .parameterEncodingFailed(let reason):
                                                        print("Parameter encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                        print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                                                    case .multipartEncodingFailed(let reason):
                                                        print("Multipart encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                        print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                                                    case .responseValidationFailed(let reason):
                                                        print("Response validation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                        print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")

                                                        switch reason {

                                                        case .dataFileNil, .dataFileReadFailed:
                                                            print("Downloaded file could not be read")
                                                        case .missingContentType(let acceptableContentTypes):
                                                            print("Content Type Missing: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                                                        case .unacceptableContentType(let acceptableContentTypes, let responseContentType):
                                                            print("Response content type: \(responseContentType) was unacceptable: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                                                        case .unacceptableStatusCode(let code):
                                                            print("Response status code was unacceptable: \(code)")
                                                            statusCode = code
                                                        }
                                                    case .responseSerializationFailed(let reason):

                                                        print("Response serialization failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                        print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                                                        // statusCode = 3840 ???? maybe..
                                                    }

                                                    print("Underlying error: \(error.underlyingError)")
                                                }
                                                else if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {

                                                    print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    print("Unknown error: \(response.result.error)")
                                                }

                                                print("\(statusCode)") // the status code

                                                CompletionHandler(false, TempresponseDict)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {

                                            CompletionHandler(false, NSDictionary())
                                        }
                                    }

                                case .failure(let encodingError):

                                    print(encodingError)
                                    CompletionHandler(false, NSDictionary())
                                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: fullLink I must put it as string or as urlrequest because in the second case it give me null so the video is not uploaded

Comment: , and this part I don't understand it , how I can dealing if I have 2 parameters like my code above .
for (key, value) in param {

                    //let data = (value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                    let data = (value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: key as! String)
                }

Comment: fullLink = String

Comment: for (key, value) in param {

                    //let data = (value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                    let data = (value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: key as! String)
                }

no need this code fro your senario.

Comment: You can write 2 time this line with your data.
multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image", fileName: "imagefilename", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

Comment: Ok , what is about this error in your code , this is in swift 3?
 Use of unresolved identifier 'CompletionHandler'

Comment: Thanks , I solved that and it's working perfectly now.